# failed to perform DateTime test with pytest in Flask API

Tags: python, datetime, flask, pytest

I have the problem to perform a test.

in my database there is a date field, which I need to insert, I'm trying to simulate this data insertion by pytest, using fixtures.

but I always get a json serialization error.

-- this is the test of my route

```
def test_cadastro_tipo_eventos(app, new_tipo_evento):
        with app.app_context():
   

    json_data = json.dumps(new_tipo_evento)       
    
    response = app.test_client().post(
        '/api/v1/cadastro-evento/tipo-evento',
        data=json_data,
        content_type='application/json'
    )

    assert response.status_code == 200`
```

already tried `json_data = json.dumps(new_tipo_evento, default=str)`

the fixture

```
@fixture
def new_tipo_evento():

   return {
    "fk_cliente": 1,
    "nome_do_tipo_evento": "Festa Junina",
    "periodicidade": 4,
    "dataSazonal": "Thu, 02 Feb 2023 00:00:00 GMT" ,
    "requerResposta": True,
    "tolerancia": 3,
    "unidade": "Mês",
    "qual_tipo_evento": None,
    "ehResposta": None
}
```

the field is this
`sazonal_periodo = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=None)`

```
@eventos.post('/tipo-evento')
def tipoevento():

    try:
        formulario = request.get_json()

        fk_cliente = formulario['fk_cliente']
        nome_do_evento = formulario['nome_do_tipo_evento']
        periodicidade = formulario['periodicidade']
        sazonal_periodo = formulario["dataSazonal"]
        requer_resposta = formulario["requerResposta"]
        tempo_de_tolerancia = formulario['tolerancia']
        unidade_de_tempo = formulario['unidade']
        resposta = formulario["ehResposta"]
        resposta_para = formulario["qual_tipo_evento"]
       

        tipo_evento = TipoDeEventos(
            fk_cliente=fk_cliente,
            nome_do_evento=nome_do_evento,
            periodicidade=periodicidade,
            sazonal_periodo=sazonal_periodo,
            requer_resposta=requer_resposta,
            tempo_de_tolerancia=tempo_de_tolerancia,
            unidade_de_tempo=unidade_de_tempo,
            resposta=resposta,
            resposta_para=resposta_para
        )

        db.session.add(tipo_evento)
        db.session.commit()
        
        return jsonify({'status':True, "mensagem":"Cadastro Realizado","data":tipo_evento.to_json()}), HTTP_200_OK
```

this is the route

the route works when it is being used normally.

but when i run pytest it gives this error

> FAILED src/tests/test_cadastros_.py::test_cadastro_tipo_eventos - TypeError: Object of type StatementError is not JSON serializable

```
value = '2023-02-02'

    def process(value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif isinstance(value, datetime_datetime):
            return format_ % {
                "year": value.year,
                "month": value.month,
                "day": value.day,
                "hour": value.hour,
                "minute": value.minute,
                "second": value.second,
                "microsecond": value.microsecond,
            }
        elif isinstance(value, datetime_date):
            return format_ % {
                "year": value.year,
                "month": value.month,
                "day": value.day,
                "hour": 0,
                "minute": 0,
                "second": 0,
                "microsecond": 0,
            }
        else:
>           raise TypeError(
                "SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python "
                "datetime and date objects as input."
            )
E           sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
E           [SQL: INSERT INTO main.tipo_de_eventos (fk_cliente, nome_do_evento, periodicidade, sazonal_periodo, requer_resposta, tempo_de_tolerancia, unidade_de_tempo, resposta, resposta_para) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
E           [parameters: [{'sazonal_periodo': '2023-02-02', 'fk_cliente': 1, 'tempo_de_tolerancia': 3, 'nome_do_evento': 'Festa Junina', 'unidade_de_tempo': 'Mês', 'requer_resposta': True, 'periodicidade': 4, 'resposta_para': None}]]
```

I summarized the error

I've tried several date formats, I've used

```
datetime.strptime("2023-02-22 10:10:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
datetime(2023, 8, 24, 10, 0, 0)
"2023-02-02"
"Thu, 02 Feb 2023 00:00:00 GMT"
```

but the error is always in json serialization